# Increase the refresh rate on my monitor

Tags: video, windows-vista, monitors

I recently purchased a new computer and I am using the Integrated Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3100 as my primary video output.  I connected my 23" Full HD WideScreen monitor and when I use the latest version of iTunes, my screen starts to flicker.

I check the refresh rate and it is set to 60 mhz and I can not increase it.  I checked the current driver under device manager and it has "Generic PnP Monitor" driver.

Is there a way for me to increase the refresh rate without installing a video card?

**UPDATE**

It is an LCD monitor that is hooked up to a VGA port.  It does not have an on-board DVI port.

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the my monitor drivers from "Generic PnP Monitor" to the my monitor's drivers and it did not allow me to increase the refresh rate.  Also, the flicking still occurs when I use the latest version of iTunes.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, TFT displays have a fixed refresh rate of 60Hz. This problem might be more dependend on the (slow) speed of the integrated graphics device that is too slow to handle this resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the monitor's manufacturer site and see if there are any drivers or utilities to use with this device. Install them, and restart the system for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already installed the motherboard drivers set, sometimes that package includes some sort of video drivers/utilities as well.  It sounds like you just need to install some more specific video drivers to be able to tweak that sort of setting.

Answer (score 1):

You say, "23" Full HD WideScreen monitor" which I presume to mean that you have some type of LCD. If so, the standard refresh rate is 60Hz. On some really large LCDs, the manufacturers have created a type of kludge referred to as 120Hz refresh.  Is this device connected to a VGA port or a DVI port. Presuming your card has both, make sure it's connected to DVI. If it's connected to VGA, you might be seeing a conversion problem related to your chosen resolution. Try dropping it to 1024x768 (ack!) and move up from there.

If you aren't using an LCD, then you want to start with drivers and move from there.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, LCDs have a set refresh rate of 60 Hz.

Use specific drivers for the monitor itself, make sure you have the most up-to-date drivers for the GMA 3100, and make sure hardware acceleration is turned on.

Also, some LCDs work better with the DVI port if it has one. If you aren't using it, that may be part of the problem.

If none of this helps the issue, the GMA 3100 may just be too underpowered for your screen resolution. If it works properly at a lower resolution, you know this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you generally can't change the refresh rate of an LCD display.

Running high resolution displays off of an analog connection is a recipe for eye strain in my opinion. Some specific combination of monitors/computers work well, some do not. Some examples

- Thinkpad x60 with Intel Video with VGA out to a Dell WFP2408 looks pretty darn good
- Thinkpad x60 with Intel Video with VGA out to a Dell SP2309W looks horrible.
- Dell Latitude E5400 with Intel Video with VGA out to a Dell WFP2408, awful
- Dell Latitude E5400 with Intel Video with VGA out to a Dell SP2903W, awful.
- Dell Latitude E5400 with Intel Video with VGA out to a Dell WFP1904, great
- Thinkpad t400 with ATI Video with VGA output to Dell WFP2408, not good.
- Thinkpad t400 with ATI Video with VGA output to Del SP2309W, awful.
- Dell Latitude d630 with nvidia video and VGA out to a Dell WFP2408, pretty darn good
- Dell Latitude d630 with nvidia video and VGA out to a Dell SP2903W, not good

My rule is; don't bother with a high resolution display (greater than 1280x1024 or 1440x900) unless you can use a DVI (or HDMI) connection.

Answer (score 0):

Is the flickering associated with the entire display or just the iTunes window?  If it's just the window then it's possible that you have a problem related to rendering the movie and not the display.  Check that the movie is on a local hard drive (not streaming over a network or being downloaded from a file share.)  Try running a movie file via QuickTime instead of inside iTunes.  Also check the refresh with another, simpler, movie like a cartoon.  You may have luck by upgrading drivers or iTunes.